# Working with an X2 visa in China

Tags: visa, working-visas, student-visa, china

I am currently living and working in China as a practicum student under an X2 visa with UIBE. I am actually working for a company that has a relationship with the university, rather than actually enrolled there. I wasn't told I would be on a X2 visa before I moved here.

I am wondering if my visa is connected to the University, or my employer? Meaning if I quit the current job, can my employer cancel my visa? I am looking to switch employers but there might be a gap between one visa to the next, which is a big no no here.

Comment: An X visa is a study visa, so it is not clear what you are working and how you intend to change jobs. As an expat in China, you require a release letter from your former employer in order to legally start a new job, are you aware of this? Ask your bosses who is formally your employer and how to proceed, I don't think we can know this.

Comment: Putting on hold until OP returns to clarify.